# How to make Bootcamp Windows 10 to recognize the Wireless Magic Trackpad as a trackpad (i.e. multi touch device) instead of a regular mouse?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, mouse, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have a fresh bootcamp windows 10 home 64 with bootcamp drivers version 6.0

Both the internal trackpad and the wireless trackpad are recognized as regular mouse (just pointing and 2 axis wheels). I had to go to `regedit` and change the FlipFlopWheel property so that the scrolling is natural just because windows does not recognize it as a trackpad, which allows that configuration via regular settings interface. Also because it's recognized as a regular mouse there is no way to configure multi touch gestures.

Comment: Check out [ExtraMagic](http://extramagic.forbootcamp.org/index.htm)